# Как удалить деревья с террейна, когда мы рисуем дорогу поверх леса?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть [старый код на форумах Unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/482862/remove-trees-during-runtime.html). Но он не работает в новых версиях `Unity 2018.4.1f1 (64-bit)`, предполагаю из-за новой системы координат(от 0 до 1).

Мой код:

```
static void RemoveTrees(Terrain terrain, Vector2 position, float brushsize)
{

    TreeInstance[] trees = terrain.terrainData.treeInstances;
    List<TreeInstance> newTrees = new List<TreeInstance> ();
    Vector3 terrainDataSize = terrain.terrainData.size;
    Vector3 activeTerrainPosition = terrain.GetPosition();
    float distance;
    foreach (TreeInstance tree in trees)
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(tree.position, position);
        if (distance > brushsize)
        {
            newTrees.Add(tree);
        }
    }
    terrain.terrainData.treeInstances = newTrees.ToArray();
}
```

Как ещё улучшить написанный код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать так:

```
    if (GUILayout.Button("DeleteTree"))
    {
        Vector3 vector = new Vector3(8315f,0,5069f);
        Terrain[] TerrainList = GObjtemp.GetComponentsInChildren<Terrain>();
        for (int t=0;t<TerrainList.Count();t++) {
            if (vector.x >= TerrainList[t].GetPosition().x && vector.x <= TerrainList[t].GetPosition().x + TerrainList[t].terrainData.size.x
            && vector.z >= TerrainList[t].GetPosition().z && vector.z <= TerrainList[t].GetPosition().z + TerrainList[t].terrainData.size.z)
            {
                Debug.Log("SELECT"+TerrainList[t].name);
                CustomPaintContext.RemoveTrees(TerrainList[t],new Vector3(vector.x,TerrainList[t].SampleHeight(vector),vector.z),350f);
                //RemoveTrees(Terrain terrain, Vector2 position, float brushsize)
                break;
            }
            Debug.Log(TerrainList[t].name);
        }
    }
```

Сам код удаления деревьев:

```
   static public void RemoveTrees(Terrain terrain, Vector3 position, float brushsize)
    {
        TreeInstance[] trees = terrain.terrainData.treeInstances;
        List<TreeInstance> newTrees = new List<TreeInstance> ();
        Vector3 terrainDataSize = terrain.terrainData.size;
        Vector3 activeTerrainPosition = terrain.GetPosition();
        float distance;
        foreach (TreeInstance tree in trees)
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(Vector3.Scale(tree.position, terrainDataSize)+activeTerrainPosition,position);
            if (distance > brushsize)
            {
                newTrees.Add(tree);
            }
        }
        terrain.terrainData.treeInstances = newTrees.ToArray();
    }
```

Преобразуем координаты деревьев в `terrain.terrainData.treeInstances`. Следующим образом: `Vector3.Scale(tree.position, terrainDataSize)+activeTerrainPosition`